# If $G$ is a group of order $25$, prove that either $G$ is cyclic or else every non-identity element of $G$ has order 5 (and $G$ is not cyclic).

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$ is a group of order $25$

Prove that either $G$ is cyclic or else evry nonIdentyt element of $G$ has order 5.

---

Here are few theorems that I am trying to work with *might be irrelevant thougth*

**Thm1**
Let S be a nonempty subset of group $G$ . Let $\langle S \rangle$ be set of all possible products, in every order, of elements of $S$ and their inverses

$\Rightarrow$

1. $\langle S \rangle$ is a subgroup of set $S$
2. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ when $S \subset H \Rightarrow \langle S \rangle \leq H$

**Thm2** Every subgroup of a cyclic group is itself cyclic

**Thm3** Let $G$ be a group and let $a\in G$

1. If $a$ has infinite order then $\langle a \rangle$ is an infinite subgroup consisting of distinct $k a$, $k \in Z$

   2. If $a$ has order $n$ then $\langle a \rangle$ is a subgroup of order $n $
      and $\langle a \rangle=\{ 0,1a,2a, \dots , \dots , (n-1)a \}$

---

I don't know where to go from there or if it can be done from scratch easily.

Comment: guessing prove would be something like take an element of $Z_{25}$ it has to divide 25. so it has to be $5$ or $25$ or $1$. if its $25$ it generates the whole group. or it has order of $5$ or else its the identity right??? thats it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** By Lagrange's theorem, the order of any element divides $25$.  There is exactly one element of order $1$.  Thus, we have two cases: either the group contains an element of order $25$, or it contains no such element.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem**: A group of order $p^2$ is abelian.

**Proof:** The center of a $p$-group is non-trivial.   Thus $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic.   Thus $G$ is abelian.

Thus by the structure theorem we have one of $$\Bbb Z_{25},\Bbb Z_5×\Bbb Z_5.$$